# Why does Yahoo finance give wrong data?

Tags: historical-data, yahoo

I'm using yahoo finance to download data for a ticker called ISF.L  (it's a London based etf tracking the ftse 100).

Url : 
https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ISF.L/history?period1=1403823600&period2=1561590000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

All appears well until you look at the data, and you notice things like:

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Adj.Cl  Volume

18 May 2018 776.30  777.40  774.00  776.80  776.36  2,014,717
17 May 2018 770.30  777.70  770.10  777.70  777.26  2,729,054
16 May 2018 770.40  772.50  769.80  771.60  771.16  3,357,175
15 May 2018 10.38   10.38   10.38   10.41   10.41   1,561      <-- ???
14 May 2018 10.40   10.45   10.40   10.44   10.44   59,585
11 May 2018 10.43   10.47   10.43   10.43   10.43   118,106
10 May 2018 10.34   10.35   10.34   10.37   10.36   9,023
```

So the data seems to show a different asset is being reported on certain dates, but, perhaps there's a way to fix this?

Comment: Yap, it indeed seems inconsistent with other sources:
https://markets.ft.com/data/etfs/tearsheet/historical?s=ISF:LSE:GBX

Comment: This question comes up once in a while. The problem with Yahoo data is that you get what you pay for: not much.